# Can we play "A Way Out" on single PS4?

Tags: ps4, a-way-out

I'm thinking to buy "A Way Out" game but I'm confused a bit.

> Team up with Friends Pass - Use Friends Pass when you buy a Way Out
> and play the entire game online with any of your friends

With this statement I thought that my friend also need a PS4 but they don't have to buy the game.

And also,

> Tailored Co-Op Experience:
>
> The entire game is a co-op only experience which is best played with a
> friend.
>
> All gameplay is designed with co-op in mind, making sure the
> players need each other to progress unlike typical drop in/drop out
> experiences.
>
> **Includes the ability to play either couch or online
> co-op.**
>
> Dynamic split screen and bespoke camera work offers an
> additional level of immersion to each player.

With this sentence(bold one), I thought I can play with my friend on the same PS4 with 2 controllers.

So, I just want to clarify my doubt before buying the game.

Can I play the game with my friend on **1 PS4 with 2 controllers**?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

"Couch co-op" means that multiple players can play on the same console. It's named after the couch that people sit in when playing games together.

There's also "split screen", which is essentially a technique where the screen is split (hence the name) to show content for each of the players.

Either of those terms alone already explicitly indicate that only 1 console is needed for all players. In this case both terms are used together, so there should be absolutely no room for doubt.